# Use log4net with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, log4net

I have a console application, with Quartz, Ninject and log4net.

My question is I can't understand why this code works fine (logs working):

```
kernel.Bind<ILog>()
    .ToConstant(LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program)))
    .InSingletonScope();
```

But when I try to use with context, it is not working (logs not working empty console):

```
kernel.Bind<ILog>()
    .ToMethod(x => LogManager.GetLogger(x.Request.Target.Member.ReflectedType))
    .InSingletonScope();
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think `InSingletonScope` should be dropped when you are using context.